# Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ be a prime. If $\gcd(a^p-b^p,p) = 1$ then $p^2 \nmid a^p-b^p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm doing this proof by contradiction, I assumed that $p^2|a^p-b^p$.

I'm trying to use Fermat's little theorem but I'm not sure whether this helps or not. Hints, suggestions would be of great help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $p^2$ divides $a^p-b^p$, then $p$ does as well.  But $p$ also divides $p$.  Hence the gcd can't be 1.  It is not needed for $p$ to be prime.